# Sorting by lift and confidence using arules package in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to sort rules by confidence and lift at the same time?

I got:

```
rules_order <- sort(rules, decreasing=TRUE,by="confidence")
```

but I cannot order by both at the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting rules by lift and confidence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106764/sorting-rules-by-lift-and-confidence)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will solve your problem

```
x1 <- sort(x, by = c('support','confidence'))
```